# Simple DatePicker using it in android

Tags: java, android, datepicker

### When i click on the edit text ..... I get error as in logcat

**DatePickerDate.java**

```
public class DatePickerDate extends FragmentActivity {

    EditText mEdit;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_page);
    }

    public void selectDate(View view) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
    }
    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.DATE_EDIT_TEXT_ID);
        mEdit.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
    }
    public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
            populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
        }
    }

}
```

**search_page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="selectDate"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text="date" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/DATE_EDIT_TEXT_ID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".75"
            android:onClick="selectDate"
            android:inputType="date" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method selectDate(View) in the activity class com.project.findmybuffet.SearchPage for onClick handler on view class android.widget.EditText with id 'DATE_EDIT_TEXT_ID'
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2131)
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: selectDate
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000):     at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:247)
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:962)
10-04 23:11:42.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2000):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2124)
```

**How to resolve this !**

[Update]

**SearchPage.java**

public class SearchPage extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_page);

}


}
```

Comment: Do you have a `SearchPage` Activity that also uses that layout?

Comment: Yes i do ........ please see the upated question !

Comment: you have both activities with same layout `R.layout.search_page`

Comment: @ Raghunandan ....... I was unknowingly referencing 2 activities with same layout ... solved it ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `SearchPage` also uses your `search_page` layout, it also needs to have a `selectDate(View)` method.

When a View with `android:onClick="selectDate"` is clicked, Android will call `selectDate(View)` on the Activity currently shown to the user.

In your case, the `SearchPage` Activity is the one being shown, and the app crashes because Android cannot find `selectDate(View)` in that Activity. thus the first line of your logcat,

> Could not find a method selectDate(View) in the activity class com.project.findmybuffet.SearchPage

Comment: Solved it ..... your input helped ..... i was using 2 activities with same layout ..... its working :)

Answer (score 1):

i Guess you do not have below method in your SearchPage Activity

```
 public void selectDate(View view) {
      }
```

Thats causing problem.